# Fastest and most efficient way to get number of records (lines) in a gzip-compressed file

Tags: shell, gzip

I am trying to do a record count on a 7.6 GB gzip file. I found few approaches using the `zcat` command.

```
$ zcat T.csv.gz | wc -l
423668947
```

This works but it takes too much time (more than 10 minutes to get the count). I tried a few more approaches like

```
$ sed -n '$=' T.csv.gz
28173811
$ perl -lne 'END { print $. }' < T.csv.gz
28173811
$ awk 'END {print NR}' T.csv.gz
28173811
```

All three of these commands are executing pretty fast but giving an incorrect count of 28173811.

How can I perform a record count in a minimal amount of time?

Comment: Why do you need to count the number of records? If you're trying to count them before processing them, that means you have to uncompress the file twice.

Comment: More info on why you're doing this would be helpful.  If it's something ongoing - that is, you regularly compress a bunch of files, and at some later time need to know the number of records - why not count them as they're compressed, and embed the number in the file name?

Comment: Reading a 9.7GB file from a mechanical disk is inherently slower. Store the file on an SSD, and see how much faster the gunzip/zcat runs. But as @jamesqf says, store the linecount in the filename, or in a file in the tgz, and extracting that file will be much faster.

Comment: There are good theoretical reasons why you can't avoid this work. A compression format that lets you determine some useful property of the data "without decompressing it" is pretty much by definition not as good a compression format as it could be :)

Answer (score 30):

The `sed`, `perl` and `awk` commands that you mention may be correct, but they all read the *compressed* data and counts newline characters in that.  These newline characters have nothing to do with the newline characters in the uncompressed data.

To count the number of lines in the uncompressed data, there is no way around uncompressing it.  Your approach with `zcat` is the correct approach and since the data is so large, it *will* take time to uncompress it.

Most utilities that deals with `gzip` compression and decompression will most likely use the same shared library routines to do so.  The only way to speed it up would be to find an implementation of the `zlib` routines that are somehow faster than the default ones, and rebuild e.g. `zcat` to use those.

Comment: It would be a non-trivial programming exercise, but doable. The whole point is to _not_ rebuild `zcat`. A significant part of the work of `zcat` is generating the actual output. But if you're only counting `\n` characters, that is not necessary. `gzip` compression essentially works by replacing common long strings by shorter strings. So you only need to care about the long strings in the dictionary that contain a `\n`, and count the (weighted) occurrence of those. E.g. due to English rules, `.\n` is a common 16 bits string.

Answer (score 22):

## Use unpigz.

Kusalananda's answer is correct, you *will* need to uncompress that entire file to scan its contents. `/bin/gunzip` does this as fast as it can, on a single core. [Pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) is a parallel implementation of `gzip` that can use multiple cores.

Sadly, the decompression itself of normal gzip files cannot be parallelized, but `pigz` does offer an improved version of `gunzip`, `unpigz`, that does related work such as reading, writing, and checksumming in a separate thread. In some quick benchmarks, `unpigz` is almost twice as fast as `gunzip` on my core i5 machine.

Install `pigz` with your favourite package manager, and use `unpigz` instead of `gunzip`, or `unpigz -c` instead of `zcat`. So your command becomes:

```
$ unpigz -c T.csv.gz | wc -l
```

All this assumes the bottleneck is the CPU, not the disk, of course.

Comment: My `pigz` man page states that _Decompression  can't  be  parallelized,  at  least not without specially prepared deflate streams for that purpose.  As a result, pigz uses a single
       thread (the main thread) for decompression, but will create three other threads for reading, writing, and check  calculation,  which  can  speed  up
       decompression under some circumstances_. Still, like you I find it's at least twice as faster than `gzip`, if not because of the parallelism

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point! That explains the mildly disappointing speedup for decompression. I edited my post to reflect this information better.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with all the pipelines is that you are essentially doubling the work. No matter how fast the decompression is, the data still need to be shuttled to another process.

Perl has [PerlIO::gzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::gzip) which allows you to read gzipped streams directly. Therefore, it might offer an advantage even if its decompression speed may not match that of `unpigz`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autouse Carp => 'croak';
use PerlIO::gzip;

@ARGV or croak "Need filename\n";

open my $in, '<:gzip', $ARGV[0]
    or croak "Failed to open '$ARGV[0]': $!";

1 while <$in>;

print "$.\n";

close $in or croak "Failed to close '$ARGV[0]': $!";
```

I tried it with a 13 MB gzip compressed file (decompresses to 1.4 GB) on an old [2010 MacBook Pro with 16 GB RAM](https://www.nu42.com/2013/02/mid-2010-macbook-pro-71-with-16-gb-ddr3.html) and an old [ThinkPad T400 with 8 GB RAM](https://www.nu42.com/2016/12/another-one-bites-the-dust.html) with the file already in the cache. On the Mac, the Perl script was significantly faster than using pipelines (5 seconds vs 22 seconds), but on ArchLinux, it lost to unpigz:

```
$ time -p ./gzlc.pl spy.gz 
1154737
real 4.49
user 4.47
sys 0.01
```

versus

```
$ time -p unpigz -c spy.gz | wc -l
1154737
real 3.68
user 4.10
sys 1.46
```

and

```
$ time -p zcat spy.gz | wc -l
1154737
real 6.41
user 6.08
sys 0.86
```

Clearly, using `unpigz -c file.gz | wc -l` is the winner here both in terms of speed. And, that simple command line surely beats writing a program, however short.

Comment: I think you're greatly overestimating the resources required to move the data between two processes, compared to the decompression calculations. Try benchmarking the various approaches ;)

Comment: @SinanÜnür On my x86_64 Linux system (also old hardware) `gzip | wc` has the same speed than your perl script. And `pigz | wc`is double as fast. `gzip` runs with the same speed, regardless if I write the output to /dev/null or pipe into `wc` What I believe is that the "gzip library" used by perl is faster than the gzip command line tool. Maybe there is another Mac/Darwin specific problem with pipes.  It's still amazing that this perl version is competitive at all.

Comment: On my x86_64 Linux install, it seems to do better than `zcat` and worse than `unpigz`. I am amazed at how much faster the pipeline is on the Linux system compared to the Mac. I was not expecting that, even though I should have as I once observed the same program ran faster on a CPU limited Linux VM on that same Mac than on bare metal.

Comment: That's interesting; on my system (Debian 8.8 amd64, quad core i5), the perl script is slightly _slower_... 109M .gz file decompressing to 1.1G of text, consistently takes 5.4 secs for `zcat | wc -l`, and 5.5 secs for your perl script. Honestly, I'm amazed at the variation people are reporting here, especially between Linux and MacOS X!

Comment: I don't know if I can generalize what I am seeing on my Mac, something odd is going on. With the decompressed 1.4 GB file, `wc -l` takes 2.5 seconds. `gzcat compressed.gz > /dev/null` takes 2.7 seconds. Yet, the pipeline takes 22 seconds. If I try GNU `wc`, it takes only half a second on the decompressed file, but 22 seconds in the pipeline. GNU `zcat` takes twice as long to execute `zcat compressed.gz > /dev/null`. This is on Mavericks, old Core 2 Duo CPU, 16 GB RAM, Crucial MX100 SSD.

Comment: @marcelm What is really unsettling is if I boot a minimal ArchLinux VM on the same Mac, and try the `zcat` pipeline takes only 7.5 seconds, and the `unpigz` pipeline takes only 4.5 seconds. The input files is accessed through VirtualBox shared folders. Hmmmm ...

Answer (score 4):

Kusalananda's answer is *mostly* correct.  To count lines you need to search for newlines.  However it is theoretically possible to search for newlines without completely uncompressing the file.

gzip uses DEFLATE compression.  DEFLATE is a combination of LZ77 and Huffman encoding.  There may be a way to figure out just the Huffman symbol node for newline and ignore the rest.  There almost certainly is a way to look for newlines encoded using L277, keep a byte count and ignore everything else.

So IMHO its theoretically possible to come up with a solution more efficient than unpigz or zgrep.  That being said its certainly not practical (unless someone has already done it).

Comment: A major problem with this idea is, the Huffman symbols used by DEFLATE correspond to *bit* sequences after LZ77 compression, so there may be no simple relationship between them and U+000A characters in the uncompressed file.  For instance, maybe one Huffman symbol means the last five bits of "." followed by the first three bits of "\n", and another symbol means the last five bits of "\n" followed by all eight bits of "T".

Comment: @zwol No, the LZ77 portion of the Deflate algorithm compresses byte sequences, not bit sequences. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE#Duplicate_string_elimination

Comment: @RossRidge Huh, I didn't know that, but I don't think it invalidates what I said.  The *Huffman* symbols can, it appears to me based on the next paragraph of that reference, each expand to a variable number of bits, they don't have to produce a whole number of bytes.

Comment: @zwol Sure, you have to search for matching Huffman code bit sequences in the bit stream but this answer doesn't suggest otherwise. The problem with this answer is that determining which Huffman codes ultimately generate or more newline characters isn't simple. The LZ77 codes that generate newlines are constantly changing as the sliding window moves, which means that the Huffman codes are changing as well. You'd have to implement the entire decompression algorithm except the output part, and maybe some part of the sliding window since you're only interested in the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using  `zgrep` with `-c` flag, and `$` parameter.

In this case -c instruct the command to output number of matched lines and the regex $ matches end of line so it matches every line or the file.

```
zgrep -c $ T.csv.gz
```

As commented by @StéphaneChazelas - `zgrep` is only a script around `zcat` and `grep` and it should provide similar performance to the original suggestion of `zcat | wc -l`

Comment: Hi Yaron thanks for the answer even the zgrep is taking as much time as zcat i need find some other approach i think

Comment: `zgrep` is generally a script that invokes `zcat` (same as `gzip -dcq`) to uncompress the data and feed it to `grep`, so is not going to help.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks for the comment, update my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a parallel gzip decoder, [rapidgzip](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/rapidgzip) (previously "pragzip"), which can speed up this use case. Here is a performance comparison for counting newlines. I also added `igzip`, part of the [isal package](https://github.com/intel/isa-l), to the comparison because it is the fastest single-core gzip decompressor I know of. And I included pigz because it is often mentioned for parallel gzip handling but that is only for compression while it doesn't actually use all cores for decompression.

| Decoder | Lines | Runtime / s | Bandwidth / (MB/s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rapidgzip --count-lines | 55778796 | 0.879 | **4886** |
| rapidgzip | 55778796 | 1.309 | **3281** |
| igzip | 55778796 | 9.113 | 471 |
| pigz | 55778796 | 13.091 | 328 |
| gzip | 55778796 | 22.132 | 194 |
| zgrep | 55778797 | 23.061 | 186 |

Tested on a Ryzen 3900X with 64 GB of RAM. Of course, you will either need a fast enough SSD or use an in-memory file system like `/dev/shm`, or depending on the distribution `/tmp`, to reach these speeds.

As others have mentioned, further speedups can be reached by specializing the decoder and letting it do the counting internally instead of copying and piping the decoded data to another tool. This is what `rapidgzip --count-lines` does.

Furthermore, rapidgzip still contains many things that can be further optimized. Note that at this point you will very likely run into I/O problems first because the disk also has to keep up.

Lastly, beware that the result for zgrep as mentioned in the other answer (`zgrep -c '$' 4GiB-base64.gz`) is off by one because `wc -l` counts the number of `\n` while `zgrep -c '$'` effectively counts every line including the last one even if it does not end with `\n`!

This is the script I used to benchmark:

```bash
sudo apt install pigz isal
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade rapidgzip
# Create a compressible random file with many newlines
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c $(( 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 )) > 4GiB-base64
gzip -c 4GiB-base64

fileSize=$( stat -L --format=%s 4GiB-base64 )
printf '\n| %7s | %8s | %10s | %18s |\n' Decoder Lines 'Runtime / s' 'Bandwidth / (MB/s)'
printf -- '|---------|----------|-------------|--------------------|\n'
for tool in rapidgzip igzip pigz gzip; do
    lineCount=$( $tool -d -c "4GiB-base64.gz" | wc -l )
    runtime=$( ( time $tool -d -c "4GiB-base64.gz" | wc -l ) 2>&1 | sed -n -E 's|real[ \t]*0m||p' | sed 's|[ \ts]||' )
    bandwidth=$( python3 -c "print( int( round( $fileSize / 1e6 / $runtime ) ) )" )
    printf '| %7s | %8s | %11s | %18s |\n' "$tool" "$lineCount" "$runtime" "$bandwidth"
done

lineCount=$( zgrep -c '$' "4GiB-base64.gz" )
runtime=$( ( time zgrep -c '$' "4GiB-base64.gz" ) 2>&1 | sed -n -E 's|real[ \t]*0m||p' | sed 's|[ \ts]||' )
bandwidth=$( python3 -c "print( int( round( $fileSize / 1e6 / $runtime ) ) )" )
printf '| %7s | %8s | %11s | %18s |\n' "zgrep" "$lineCount" "$runtime" "$bandwidth"

lineCount=$( rapidgzip --count-lines "4GiB-base64.gz" )
runtime=$( ( time rapidgzip --count-lines "4GiB-base64.gz" ) 2>&1 | sed -n -E 's|real[ \t]*0m||p' | sed 's|[ \ts]||' )
bandwidth=$( python3 -c "print( int( round( $fileSize / 1e6 / $runtime ) ) )" )
printf '| %7s | %8s | %11s | %18s |\n' "rapidgzip --count-lines" "$lineCount" "$runtime" "$bandwidth"
```

Rapidgzip can also be used as a library from Python. Line counting could be done like this:

```bash
python3 -m pip install --user rapidgzip
```

```
import rapidgzip
result = 0
with rapidgzip.open("silesia.tar.gz") as file:
    while chunk := file.read( 1024*1024 ):
        result += chunk.count(b'\n')
print("Number of newlines:", result)
```

Note that performance is significantly impacted by the chunk size used for the read call and even Python's count function might be a bottleneck. I have not benchmarked this implementation.

Comment: How can I do the equivalent of `pragzip --count-lines` in a python script?

Comment: @JamesHirschorn I appended the answer to your question to my StackOverflow answer because it does not fit into a comment.

Comment: Nice. It works good.

Comment: If `zgrep -c $` is off by one because there's extra data after the last line, that would be on non-text files. The behaviour of `grep` is unspecified on such input, some ignoring those extra bytes some treating them as an extra line (and I suppose some could report  an error).

Comment: Note that in POSIX `sed` `[ \t]` is required to match on either space, backslash or `t` (GNU `sed` is only POSIX compliant in that regard when there's `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in its environment)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, most answers tries to optimize what it can: the number of the context switches and inter-process IO. The reason is, this is the only what you can optimize here easily.

Now the problem is that its resource need is nearly negligible to the resource need of the decompression. This is why the optimizations won't really make anything faster.

Where it could be really accelerated, it would be a modified un-gzip (i.e. decompression) algorithm, which leaves out the actual production of the decompressed data stream; rather it only calculates the number of the newlines in the *decompressed stream* from the *compressed* one. It would be hard, it would require the deep knowledge of the gzip's algorithm (some combination of the [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) and [Huffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) compression algorithms). It is quite probable, that the algorithm doesn't make it possible to significantly optimize the decompression time with the lightening, that we only need to know the newline counts. Even if it would be possible, essentially a new gzip decompression library should have been developed (it doesn't exists until know).

The realistic answer to your question is, that no, you can't make it significantly faster.

Maybe you could use some parallelized gzip decompression, if it exists. It could use multiple CPU cores for the decompression. If it doesn't exist, it could be relatively easily developed.

For the *xz*, there exists a parallel compressor (pxz).